# Why is the energy of this ball is increasing?

Tags: java, android, game-physics

I've been trying from hours to setup gravity and relate it to time or what we call frame independent bounce ball. I did everything correct I guess, and I tried to implement the system where height of ball would decrease after every bounce. I did not even start that, and my code is creating something absurd I don't understand why. Here's my code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        currentFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

        dt = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        dt = dt/1000;

        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        myFreakinRect.set(0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        freakinRed.setColor(Color.RED);
        freakinRed.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawRect(myFreakinRect, freakinRed);


        //

        // o yuea

        if(goingDown) {
            //velocityY = Math.sqrt(100 + 2*gravity*(posY));
            velocityY = gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);
        } else {
            velocityY = downV - gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);
        }


        if(posX > w - ballRadius*2) {
            goingRight = false;
        }
        if(posX < 0) {
            goingRight = true;
        }
        if(posY > h - ballRadius*2) {
            //initY = initY - 0.25F;
            //if(initY < 0) initY = 0;
            Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(initY));
            runTime = currentFrame;
            downV = velocityY;
            goingDown = false;
        }
        if(velocityY <= 0) {
            goingDown = true;
            runTime = currentFrame;
        }

        if(goingDown) posY += velocityY*dt;
        else posY -= velocityY*dt;

        if(goingRight) posX += velocityX*dt;
        else posX -= velocityX*dt;




        canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(posX)+"  "+String.valueOf(posY), 10, 10, new Paint());
        canvas.drawBitmap(rBall, (float)posX, (float)posY, myFreakingFaintPaint);


        invalidate();
    }
```

Here's a GIF what is happening:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Here's my updated code which is clean, understandable and works perfect:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        currentFrame = System.currentTimeMillis();

        dt = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        dt = dt/1000;

        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        velocityY = downV + gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);
        posY += velocityY*dt;
        posX += velocityX*dt;
        if(posX > w - ballRadius*2 || posX < 0) {
            velocityX = -velocityX;
        }

        if(posY >= h - ballRadius*2) {
            posY = h - ballRadius*2 - 2;
            runTime = currentFrame;
            downV = -0.8*velocityY;
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(rBall, (float)posX, (float)posY, null);


        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Conservation of energy for elastic collisions is not being satisfied.  You start with the ball at a given height, which means it has a fixed amount of gravitational potential energy.    The total of the potential and kinetic energy has to be unchanged at every point in time.

Comment: With this `if(velocityY <= 0) {` and this `posY += velocityY*dt` you count the last leg toward the wrong direction. You should not consider the speed to depend on the direction. It should be positive in one direction (e.g. going down) and negative in the other, instead of explicitely reversing it by hand.

Comment: Why `if(goingDown)...`?  The real-world laws of physics don't change depending on whether the ball is rising or falling.  There _will_ be a discontinuity in the vertical component of velocity when the ball changes from falling to rising (i.e., when it bounces).  At that point, if the collision with the floor is perfectly elastic, you simply change the sign of the vertical component.  But, there's no discontinuity when the ball reaches its max height and then starts to fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ...

> ```
>     if(goingDown) {
>         //velocityY = Math.sqrt(100 + 2*gravity*(posY));
>         velocityY = gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);
>     } else {
>         velocityY = downV - gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);
>     }
> ```

... you update the velocity (speed, actually) assuming that the ball will not bounce during this frame.

Then here ...

> ```
>     if(posY > h - ballRadius*2) {
>         //initY = initY - 0.25F;
>         //if(initY < 0) initY = 0;
>         Log.i("xxx", String.valueOf(initY));
>         runTime = currentFrame;
>         downV = velocityY;
>         goingDown = false;
>     }
> ```

... you have not yet updated `posY`, so you are determining whether the ball hit the floor as a result of the *previous* update.  If it did, you reverse the direction of motion, but keep the speed you already computed for this frame.  As a result, each time the ball bounces, its initial upward speed is one frame's worth of acceleration greater than the speed it was traveling when it hit the floor.

You have a similar effect at the top of the ball's motion, but it's smaller because the speed is small there.

There are a couple of ways you might solve this problem.  The simplest is probably to perform the bounce check after the position update instead of before.

Additional notes:

- use the signs of your X and Y speeds instead of separate direction-of-motion flags (thus making the names `velocityY` *etc*. accurate).  Your code will be simpler, and you'll need to handle only one change of vertical direction, not two, because the equations of motion will handle the other automatically.
- you have a bit of a precision problem because you assume that the ball travels in the same direction for a whole frame.  This may become noticeable if you allow the ball to reach high speeds: it will appear to penetrate the floor before bouncing back up.
- this computation is suspicious: `dt = dt/1000`.  Since `dt` seems to be computed from `System.currentTimeMillis()`, I am inclined to guess that it, too, has type `long`.  In that case, you are performing an integer division and thereby losing precision.

Comment: Thank you, I've made it to work. Check the question for updated code :)

Answer (score 1):

In general:
Split up into model and view. In that case the rendering still runs fine, because the calculations are pretty light-weight, but you shouldn't run code inside the rendering-routine that isn't directly related to painting something.

Next point:
Stay as close to reality as possible, if you simulate physics. You can always optimize afterwards, but first make sure your code is actually doing what it's supposed to do. I'm currently playing a bit around with projectile-motion, so I've got a basic idea of what the code is supposed to do. I've been attempting to understand yout code for 10 mins so far. Interim result: I'm confused and don't quite get it.

My suggestion:
Start off with clearer code and try to stick as close to physical rules as possible. This code isn't optimized as far as it could be, but it's readable, understandable and simulates close enough to the real life. That makes it a lot simpler to debug:

```
final double GRAVITY = -9.81;
final double BALL_ELASTICITY = 0.95;

double vx, vy;
double x, y;

//dt is delta-time in seconds!!!
void simulateBall(double dt){
    //calculate when the ball will touch the floor the next time
    double next_floor_touch = (-vy + Math.sqrt(vy * vy - 2 * GRAVITY * y)) / GRAVITY;
    double after_floor_touch = dt - next_floor_touch;
    boolean touches_floor = (next_floor_touch <= dt);

    //calculate new y
    if(touches_floor){
        //predict the speed the ball will have, after it bounces from the floor
        double vy_at_floor = vy + GRAVITY * next_floor_touch;
        double vy_from_floor = vy_at_floor * (-1) * BALL_ELASTICITY;

        //predict y starting from the floor at t = next_floor_touch until dt
        y = 0 + vy_from_floor * after_floor_touch + 0.5 * GRAVITY * after_floor_touch * after_floor_touch;
     }else{
        //uniform acceleration
        y = y + vy * dt + 0.5 * GRAVITY * dt * dt;
     }

     //calculate vy
     if(touches_floor){
         //see above
         double vy_after_floor = (vy + GRAVITY * next_floor_touch) * (-1) * BALL_ELASTICITY;
         vy = vy_after_floor + GRAVITY * after_floor_touch;
     }else{
         vy = vy + GRAVITY * dt;
     }

     ... //that's already the hardest part
}
```

This uses the [quadratic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) to predict when the ball will hit the floor and [uniform acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration#Uniform_acceleration) to calculate the position from a given position, speed and acceleration. Unless I've made any mistakes in my calculation (this code is **not** tested), this should be physically precise. `BALL_ELASTICITY` represents how much of the speed is left, after the ball hits the floor. That's not physically precise - might be, IDK - , but should do for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I've coded it another way, and you'd like it because this time I think its logical, clean and it works :)

Comment: @MehulMohan still a bit too many variables without clear use, and you forgot the fact, that you need to take account of the acceleration to calculate the position, but it's a lot better to understand and more precise than the previous solution :)

Comment: gravity variable handles acceleration and therefore velocityY and thus posY :)

Comment: @MehulMohan take a look at the article about uniform acceleration. Gravity handles acceleration, which handles velocityY, yes. But there's a logical mistake: `velocityY` is the speed **at the end** of the simulated timeslot. The speed changes over time, so `velocityY * dt` is nothing but a mere approximation of the final y-position.

Comment: `velocityY = downV + gravity*(currentFrame - runTime);` calculates the velocity for the current frame independently from any previous/future frame. And `dt` is the time for last frame. So I do `posY += velocityY*dt;` to add that much particular posY coord. I don't understand the logical mistake here. I've just broken apart the formula and applied it separately on both velocity and position. @Paul

Comment: @MehulMohan no you didn't. The formula is `y' = y + vy * dt + 0.5 * gravity * dt ^ 2` and `vy' = vy + gravity * dt`. Your formula calculates `vy'` correctly and reuses it to calculate the position, so your formula for the position would look like this: `y' = y + vy' * dt = y + vy + gravity * dt ^ 2`. You're missing the 0.5, which can make quite a bit of a difference.